# Confusion about "python3-ldap" and "ldap3"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-ldap

We have an older app that is running on a Redhat 7 machine and was originally written in python 2.x and imports and uses "ldap3".

We are now starting to upgrade to Redhat 8 and since it comes with Python 3, but there is no "python-ldap" in the repo, we installed "python3-ldap" using yum ("yum install python3-ldap").

We still need to use that app, so we are testing that older app with the Python3 that comes with Redhat 8, but it gave an error saying that it could not import "ldap3".

This page:

```
https://pypi.org/project/python3-ldap/
```

says "python3-ldap HAS BEEN RENAMED ldap3 to avoid confusion with the former python-ldap project." and "project renamed ldap3 - please install the ldap3 package instead of python3-ldap", so why would we be getting an import error?

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No moduled named "ldap3"
```

We were eventually able to get past that error by downloading the source from:

```
https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3
```

But we still don't understand why the import was failing, even though we had installed the "python3-ldap" using yum?

Are there two distinct things (a 'python3-ldap' RPM and a 'python3-ldap'/'ldap3' Python package)?

Thanks in advance!

Jim

Comment: As it says you need to install [`ldap3`](https://pypi.org/project/ldap3/). Note that `python3-ldap` is not updated since 2015

Comment: `yum search python ldap` yields (among others) `python3-ldap` and `python3-ldap3`. `yum info` then tells us the former is from the OS repos and links to upstream python-ldap.org which is pypi.org/project/python3-ldap -- the latter is from EPEL and links to upstream https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3

So yes, these are distinct python libraries in separate rpm packages.